# “Non Zero Exit Status” R 3.6.0 "Biobase"

Tags: r, windows-subsystem-for-linux, bioconductor, install.packages

I need to install different packages on R. The OS is ubuntu for windows. When I try "BiocManager::install("Biobase") I get the following error:

```
** R
** data
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
** checking absolute paths in shared objects and dynamic libraries
mv: cannot move '/home/mark/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/00LOCK-Biobase/00new/Biobase' to '/home/mark/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/Biobase': Permission denied
ERROR:   moving to final location failed
```

There seems to be something wrong with the permission to move certain files.. I already tried giving permission to write for everyone into the /3.6 directory, This didn't change anything.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Apparently, this is a new feature in 3.6.  But this should solve your problem:

`Sys.setenv(R_INSTALL_STAGED = FALSE)`

Comment: Thanks jake! Can someone comment on why this new feature was introduced?

Comment: @FedericoGiorgi See this post on the blog https://developer.r-project.org/Blog/public/2019/02/14/staged-install/:  "Staged installation is a new feature of R CMD INSTALL in R-devel, which is intended to be soon turned on by default. It isolates packages during installation time so that they are not accidentally accessed by other R sessions, which is key to correct function of parallel installation, but is relevant to any installation that may use multiple R sessions."