# ps and processx package update fail

Tags: r, processx

I am trying to install a package ver. developer from github, which requires to update the `ps` and `processx` packages. RStudio is running in administrative mode in Windows 10 and the environment is empty. Moreover, both `ps` and `processx` packages are not loaded. But, I am still getting an error i.e. permission denied. I tried a solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56615734/r-package-ps-fails-to-install-because-permission-denied-to-mv-in-final-step-of), but it doesn't work, how can this be fixed?

```
Warning messages:
1: In file.copy(savedcopy, lib, recursive = TRUE) :
  problem copying C:\Users\ABC\OneDrive\Documents\R\win-library\4.0\00LOCK\ps\libs\x64\ps.dll to C:\Users\ABC\OneDrive\Documents\R\win-library\4.0\ps\libs\x64\ps.dll: Permission denied
2: In file.copy(savedcopy, lib, recursive = TRUE) :
  problem copying C:\Users\ABC\OneDrive\Documents\R\win-library\4.0\00LOCK\processx\libs\x64\processx.dll to C:\Users\ABC\OneDrive\Documents\R\win-library\4.0\processx\libs\x64\processx.dll: Permission denied
```

Comment: Do you have more than one instance of R/RStudio running on that machine? Maybe try restarting the machine just to be sure.

Comment: @MrFlick, no just 1 instance is running, alright I'll try again and report back after restarting the computer.

Comment: @MrFlick, restarting the computer fixed the error, cheers.